# Can you have more than one CAEAGLLayer onscreen at a time?

Tags: iphone, ipad, opengl-es

Can a second OpenGL ES CAEAGLLayer be rendered simultaneously along with an existing OpenGL ES layer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I've had at least 9 on the screen at once, in a screen something like Photo Booth.

Comment: ok. I need to add a window into my app screen as the one that shows "two players running in EA SPORTS CRICKET game" how can i do something like that???